# How to select counts of 1 column in 1 query

Tags: db2

I want the below queries as single query.

My intention is to get just the count where `job_status = A`, where `job_status = A` and the total.

```
select 
    WORKSTATION_NAME AS CPU,
    count(*) AS TOTAL 
from 
    MDL.JOB_HISTORY_V 
where 
    MONTH(JOB_RUN_DATE_TIME) = 01 
    AND YEAR(JOB_RUN_DATE_TIME) = 2015 
GROUP BY 
    WORKSTATION_NAME

select 
    WORKSTATION_NAME AS CPU,
    count(*) AS SUCCESS_RUNS 
from 
    MDL.JOB_HISTORY_V 
where 
    JOB_STATUS = 'S' 
    and MONTH(JOB_RUN_DATE_TIME) = 01 
    AND YEAR(JOB_RUN_DATE_TIME) = 2015 
GROUP BY 
    WORKSTATION_NAME

select 
    WORKSTATION_NAME AS CPU, 
    count(*) AS ABEND_RUNS 
from 
    MDL.JOB_HISTORY_V 
where 
    JOB_STATUS = 'A' 
    and MONTH(JOB_RUN_DATE_TIME) = 01 
    AND YEAR(JOB_RUN_DATE_TIME) = 2015 
GROUP BY 
    WORKSTATION_NAME
```

Comment: > where job_status = A, where job_status = A ?

Comment: where job_status = A, where job_status = S.
these are possible values..A, S F..etc

Comment: Side note: doing stuff like `MONTH(JOB_RUN_DATE_TIME) = 01` will prevent the optimizer from using an index.  This will likely cause the system to do a complete table scan, resulting in longer run times.  You want to do something like `JOB_RUN_DATE_TIME >= '2015-01-01' AND JOB_RUN_DATE_TIME < '2015-02-01'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can count with conditions as in:

```
select WORKSTATION_NAME AS CPU
    ,  count(*) AS TOTAL
    ,  count(case when JOB_STATUS = 'S' then 1 end) as SUCCESS_RUNS
    ,  count(case when JOB_STATUS = 'A' then 1 end) as ABEND_RUNS 
from MDL.JOB_HISTORY_V 
where MONTH(JOB_RUN_DATE_TIME) = 01 
  AND YEAR(JOB_RUN_DATE_TIME) = 2015 
GROUP BY WORKSTATION_NAME
```

Comment: Glad it worked out. Don't forget to mark it as an answer since that will make it easier for others to track

Comment: done..i have issue, how to use substr as the csv is not opening fine form the output file?

Comment: and when i use below querry to export in outfile. there are no column headings.
/opt/TWS/TWA/TWS/db2inst1/sqllib/bin/db2 "export to daily.csv of del select WORKSTATION_NAME AS CPU
    ,  count(*) AS TOTAL
    ,  count(case when JOB_STATUS = 'S' then 1 end) as SUCCESS_RUNS
    ,  count(case when JOB_STATUS = 'A' then 1 end) as ABEND_RUNS 
from MDL.JOB_HISTORY_V 
where MONTH(JOB_RUN_DATE_TIME) = 03 
  AND YEAR(JOB_RUN_DATE_TIME) = 2015 
GROUP BY WORKSTATION_NAME"